# Why does code run slower in linear fashion than in a loop?

Tags: c++, c, performance, architecture

So I am measuring some latencies for how long it takes it execute an add instruction on my machine to get an estimate of CPI. I first wrote a linear version that implemented a serial add (interleaved to take advantage of pipeline). I then took the same code and wrapped the additions in a loop and reevaluated it. I understand the effects of loop level parallelism but I don't get how it would be faster than the serial version which should still implement DLP. I thought maybe it was because the loop unrolling version is taking more advantage of the pipeline through register renaming so there is a higher IPC but I also tried increasing the interleaving of the linear version and it didn't really increase the performance. I would think that branch mispredictions would cause the looped version to be quite a bit slower but thats not the case. Any thoughts?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ONE asm volatile( "add $20, %eax; add $10, %ecx");
#define FIVE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE
#define TWOFIVE FIVE FIVE FIVE FIVE FIVE
#define HUNDO TWOFIVE TWOFIVE TWOFIVE TWOFIVE
#define THOUSAND  HUNDO HUNDO HUNDO HUNDO HUNDO HUNDO HUNDO HUNDO HUNDO HUNDO
#define TENTHOUSAND THOUSAND THOUSAND THOUSAND THOUSAND THOUSAND THOUSAND THOUSAND THOUSAND THOUSAND THOUSAND
#define HUNDREDK  TENTHOUSAND TENTHOUSAND TENTHOUSAND TENTHOUSAND TENTHOUSAND TENTHOUSAND TENTHOUSAND TENTHOUSAND TENTHOUSAND TENTHOUSAND
#define MILLION  HUNDREDK HUNDREDK HUNDREDK HUNDREDK HUNDREDK HUNDREDK HUNDREDK HUNDREDK HUNDREDK HUNDREDK

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void){
    unsigned end, start;
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc" : "=a"(start), "=d"(end));
    return ((unsigned long long)start) | (((unsigned long long)end)<<32);
}
int main(){
    double CPI = 0;
    long long start, end;
    long long clocks;
    int i;
    start=rdtsc();
    for(i=0; i < 10000; i++){
        HUNDREDK
    }
    end=rdtsc();
    //calculate the time elapsed in ns per access
    clocks = end-start;
    CPI = clocks/(double)(200000*10000); //divide by Number of instructions * loop

    printf("Cycles Per Instruction %lf, Clocks %Ld\n", CPI, clocks);
}
```

The difference between the two is pretty significant. The linear version has a IPC of about .2 and the looped version has an IPC of about 4. And yes I remembered to change the amount of instructions I was dividing by when evaluating the two :)

Maybe there is some confusion about the way I am doing this because file size is not the issue. I am simply removing the loop. The two process a different amount of instructions, but I also change the value I am dividing by at the end. The end with the same compiled size.

UPDATE:
Thanks for the responses. There were a couple issues. The first being the way I was doing my measurements the IF time for one version was being amortized across the loop while the other wasn't. I ran some more code and interleaving of instructions from the Loop Level parallelism was greater in loop than in the serial version. The serial version still has some Write after Write dependencies that are not being renamed and are causing stalls to the pipeline.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "with and without the loop"?

Comment: When you run without the loop, you do remember to remove the `*10000` from the CPI calculation, don't you? =)

Comment: If i remove the loop and run the code linearly, I.E unroll it by hand then it is much slower. And @Arkku yes I did :)

Comment: In any case if you're expanding the loop to be anywhere near the same number of `add` operations, your code will get so large that moving the code data through the caches will dominate the time taken. I would guess a matter of code size vs. number of instructions.

Comment: @jeremycole, ive measured this across all of the caches and varying levels of instruction/file size and it remains pretty consistent.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't the `printf` formatters be `%f` and `%lld`?

Comment: RAM is much slower than cache.  Something like 50 cycles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that because you've unrolled such a large number of iterations the code is very large. The overhead of constantly loading new pages of commands into the cache is much higher than that of iterating a variable.

In terms of branch mispredictions the loop should actually have very few. It will predict the branch that is used most often, which is right 9999/10000 times. Branch prediction is actually very good.

Comment: Yup, basically unrolling loops has limits. It can help if the number of iterations is fairly small but unrolling a loop this large is sure to be slower.

Comment: I have tried this with varying number of instructions and had them span all the different caches. Also, the code size of the two is close to the same.

Comment: @PandaRaid If you think the code size is the same, you're not measuring it correctly.

Comment: Out of cursiosity, how large are the executables?

Comment: Hmm, if you simply remove the loop and the `*10000` from the calculation, then the code size should be the same - both have 200K unrolled instructions.

Comment: For pure-loop 10000 * 100000 x ONE I get 8.4 KB, for mixed loop 10000 x HUNDREDK I get 597 KB.

Comment: Yes, the code size is the same and I am measuring it based on the size of the object file. I have done it with a large variety of sizes, this particular one was around 610k.

Comment: @Arkku Yes, although you're not running the same total number of operations then.

Comment: @jeremycole True, but 200K might be enough not to matter. To be safe both could have `MILLION` instead of `HUNDREDK`.

Comment: I get similar results to @jeremycole, for the final executable. Keep in mind the obj file has a lot of other junk. Including something like `<iostream>` will add 500K to the executable as well.

Comment: I obviously didn't have the timing or reporting code.

Comment: Ah, this seems to be something entirely different. Will write an answer.

Comment: That's not really a reasonable comparison is it? Looping over the same thing 10k times vs. once amortizes the cost of loading the code over all 10k loops...

Comment: I would think that the cost of loading the code is relatively insignificant in regards to the total running time. Especially as the length of instructions grow. And the difference is substantial.

Comment: Hmm, yes, actually I think the better comparison might be something like 200 unrolled vs 2000 unrolled, both in a loop – an order of magnitude difference in amount of unrolling but perhaps still fitting in cache. @jeremycole is right that the 10K loop does include 10K times any overhead of loading code, and with 200K unrolled instructions there certainly will be non-zero overhead.

Comment: @PandaRaid For 200k instructions alone, (~600k) the cost of loading it is definitely not insignificant. Loading it into cache to execute only once will mean the load completely dominates the time.

Comment: Another way to prove that the cache load is dominating the time. Move the call to `HUNDREDK` into a function. Call that function once before you start the timer (code will get cached) and then time only the second call. It looks much better, then. (Drops from CPI ~4.9 to CPI ~1.2 on my test.)

Comment: Great response, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The more likely reason is hitting the L3 cache for the `MILLION` case vs. never leaving L1/L2 cache for the `HUNDREDK` case.

The size of `ONE` is somewhere between six and eight bytes ([source](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/lecture.html#X77_0210_encoding_add_immediate)) - sorry for being imprecise; not that good with assembly, but it's good enough for back-of-the-envelope calculations.

With that in mind, and assuming the best case scenario of three bytes (six bytes total for the two `add`s):

- `HUNDREDK` ~ 600 KB
- `MILLION` ~ 6 MB

Assuming an L1 cache of 64 KB and L2 cache of 256 KB ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/252933/size-of-l1-cache)), the `MILLION` code is spilling over all the way to L3 (outside of the CPU core), while `HUNDREDK` is mostly prefetched in L1 and L2 (in the CPU core) - [source for prefetching](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/08/24/what-you-need-to-know-about-prefetching)

Comment: The size of `ONE` is 6 bytes: `83 c0 14` and `83 c1 0a`.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. I have taken the size of the executable s into account and they are pulling from the same cache.

Comment: The size of the executable as whole may not be a good place to start. The size of the loop compared to the unrolled code is the piece that matters. Someone mentioned that in the comments for the first answer already (how much code `<iostream>` is adding to the executable).

Comment: @the downvoter: would be nice to get an explanation on why you think this is off mark.

Comment: @PandaRaid one quick test you could do is use a smaller unrolled size that fits into the L1 cache; it should be even faster than the HUNDREDK case.

Comment: @jeremycole: Thanks. Adjusted the answer to use 3 bytes for each add.